# Postgresql performance issue with HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, hikaricp

I am trying to load large data into one table in PostgreSQL server (40 million rows total) in small batches (6000 rows in each csv). I thought HikariCP would be ideal for this purpose.

This is the throughput I get from my data insertion using
Java 8 (1.8.0_65), Postgres JDBC driver 9.4.1211 and HikariCP 2.4.3.

**6000 rows in 4 minutes and 42 seconds.**

**What am I doing wrong and how can I improve the speed of insertion?**

Few more words about my setup:

- Program runs in my laptop behind corp network.
- Postgres server 9.4 is Amazon RDS with db.m4.large and 50 GB SSD.
- No explicit index or primary key defined created on table yet.
- Program inserts each row asynchronously with large thread pool to hold requests as below:

  ```
  private static ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 1000, 30L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100000));
  ```

DataSource configuration is:

```
        private DataSource getDataSource() {
                if (datasource == null) {
                    LOG.info("Establishing dataSource");
                    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                    config.setJdbcUrl(url);
                    config.setUsername(userName);
                    config.setPassword(password);
                    config.setMaximumPoolSize(600);// M4.large 648 connections tops
                    config.setAutoCommit(true); //I tried autoCommit=false and manually committed every 1000 rows but it only increased 2 minute and half for 6000 rows
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSourceClassName","org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.logWriter", new PrintWriter(System.out));
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "1000");
                    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
                    config.setConnectionTimeout(1000);

                    datasource = new HikariDataSource(config);
                }
                return datasource;
            }
```

This where I read source data:

```
    private void readMetadata(String inputMetadata, String source) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            FileReader fr = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputMetadata));
                String sCurrentLine = br.readLine();// skip header;
                if (!sCurrentLine.startsWith("xxx") && !sCurrentLine.startsWith("yyy")) {
                    callAsyncInsert(sCurrentLine, source);
                }
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    callAsyncInsert(sCurrentLine, source);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)
                        br.close();

                    if (fr != null)
                        fr.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
                }
            }
    }
```

I am inserting data asynchronously (or trying to with jdbc!):

```
            private void callAsyncInsert(final String line, String source) {
                    Future<?> future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                dataLoader.insertRow(line, source);
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
                                try {
                                    errorBufferedWriter.write(line);
                                    errorBufferedWriter.newLine();
                                    errorBufferedWriter.flush();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e1));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        if (future.get() != null) {
                            LOG.info("$$$$$$$$" + future.get().getClass().getName());
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
                    }
                }
```

My DataLoader.insertRow is below:

```
            public void insertRow(String row, String source) throws SQLException {
                    String[] splits = getRowStrings(row);
                    Connection conn = null;
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                    try {
                        if (splits.length == 15) {
                            String ... = splits[0];
                            //blah blah blah

                            String insertTableSQL = "insert into xyz(...) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
                            conn = getConnection();
                            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, column1);
                            //blah blah blah
                            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                            counter.incrementAndGet();
                            //if (counter.get() % 1000 == 0) {
                                //conn.commit();
                            //}
                        } else {
                            LOG.error("Invalid row:" + row);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        /*if (conn != null) {
                            conn.close();   //Do preparedStatement.close(); rather connection.close
                        }*/
                        if (preparedStatement != null) {
                            preparedStatement.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

When monitored in pgAdmin4, I noticed few things:

- the highest number of transactions per second was close to 50.
- Active database session was only one, the total number of sessions were 15.
- Too many block I/O ( hitting about 500, not sure if that should be a concern)

[image: screenshot from pgAdmin]

Comment: Reduce the size of your connection pool and nr of threads used: more connections (and more threads) don't necessarily lead to better performance, there is even a point (which is probably way below your current settings), where more connections (and threads) will actually cause a reduction in performance and throughput. Also, you **should** close the connection in your method, that returns it to the connection pool for reuse.

Comment: Also, have you actually checked if the bottleneck is with the async insert, maybe the problem is with the code you don't show (which calls `callAsyncInsert`).

Comment: Thank you for the response:

Comment: Reduced both connection pool and nr of threads to 10. Also, closed connection after insert (which closes ConnectionProxy object). There is not much of a heavy lifting where I call callAsyncInsert, just read csv and pass it to callAsyncInsert. After making these changes, it is still in 4 minutes 42 seconds. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might try not doing it async and use batch insert instead? Show the code that calls `callAsyncInsert`? Also understand that connecting from your laptop to a database hosted on AWS can have quite a bit of latency. Have you tested this against a local database?

Comment: I have updated question with the code that calls callAsyncInsert. I will try with batchInsert without async. I am not able to install local database, but my end goal is to execute this code from an EC2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely want to use batched inserts, with the statement being prepared *outside* of the loop, and auto-commit off.  In pseudo-code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into xyz(...) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
while ( <data> ) {
   stmt.setString(1, column1);
   //blah blah blah
   stmt.addBatch();
}
stmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```

Even a single thread on a single connection should be able to insert > 5000 rows/sec.

UPDATE: If you want to multi-thread it, the number of connections should be the number of database CPU cores x1.5 or 2.  The number of processing threads should match that, and each processing thread should handle one CSV file using the pattern above.  However, you may find that many concurrent inserts into the same table creates too much lock contention in the DB, in which case you need to back-off the number of processing threads until you find the optimal concurrency.

A properly sized pool and concurrency should easily be above to achieve >20K rows/sec.

Also, please upgrade to HikariCP v2.6.0.

Comment: The number of threads for multi-threaded imports is not only determined by the number of CPUs on the server but also by the number of harddisks on that server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While true, with Amazon RDS there is no way to know that number.

Comment: Ok. I have modified the program per suggestion. Upgraded to 2.6.0. Added batch insert and used only connection to load data. Now I see a great difference with 2 different types of data set. Data set #1 is 500K rows in one csv file took (499951 to be precise) - 00:02:08.670 minutes. Data set #2 is 498K in 83 CSV file with each 6K rows took 00:02:09.674 minutes.  So I am able to get throughput 3840ish/sec. I might get more if I dont have a heavy framework of macro logging, error handling etc. But I am happy with this. Thank you so much Mr Woolridge for this framework and Mark for helping out.